# Referencing bash variable name from separate file

Tags: bash, shell, variables

Assume two files: `file1` and `file2`. `file1` is a short *Bash* script, that references `file2` in order to obtain a text string. The text string includes a variable name (`$VAR1`), but the variable itself is assigned a value in `file1`.

```
$ cat file1
#!/bin/bash
VAR1="World"
CMDS=$(cat file2)
echo "$CMDS"

$ cat file2
Hello $VAR1 !
```

Under the above setup, the variable name is not recognized correctly during the execution of `file1`.

```
$ bash file1 
Hello $VAR1 !
```

What do I need to do so that the variable name is recognized correctly during the execution of `file1`?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @123 Apparently, he wants to use `bash` as a templating system.

Comment: @chepner Very odd way to approach templating.

Answer (score 0):

As you do not execute file2, just cat its content, the variable in file2 only serves as a placeholder. You could pipe the output from cat to sed, like so:

```
CMDS=$(cat file2|sed -e "s/\$VAR1/$VAR1/")
```

Comment: `sed` knows how to read `file2`. The [`cat` is useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).